# Error: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4087b120

Tags: android, menu, video-recording

I am trying to make menus button for video recording start and stop:

```
public void vid_Recorder() {
    try {
        mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);;
        mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/recorder.3gpp");
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here I had created the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem Item)
{
    switch(Item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_Start:
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started Recording",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            vid_Recorder();
            System.out.println("Get Started");
        }
        case R.id.menu_Stop:
        {
            mRecorder.stop();
        }
    }

    return onOptionItemSelected(Item);
}
```

But am not even getting that `system.out.println` statement in logcat instead of that I am getting:

> Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406f05e8

Comment: I got the solution  "public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item)"  this is the problem and I rectified it,,

Comment: What was the solution? Do you think that "I rectified it" is enough?

Comment: @Vaiden::: Sorry I totally forgot how I solved the issue, b'coz this was posted 1 yr back... I guess the error might be in calling ID (OR) instead of calling this method "vid_Recorder()" inside the boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) method might have did directly... Somehow I specified the probz is in boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) method,, hope evry 1 can get it,,